# having trouble selecting nested same class elements

Tags: css

I am having troubling finding a clean and non-hacky way of selecting my nested intro-cntnr divs. Each nested intro-cntnr gets a different transition delay. I was looking for something like an nth-type-of, which doesn't work cause they are nested. What else can I use in terms of css selectors?

```
  <div className="intro-cntnr">
        <span className="intro-msg wht"></span>
        <div className="intro-cntnr">
            <span className="intro-msg big wht"></span>
            <div className="intro-cntnr">
                <span className="intro-msg gry">
                    <span className="neon"></span>
                </span>
                <div className="intro-cntnr">
                    <div className="intro-cntnr">
                        <span className="intro-msg gry"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: There's no CSS selector for nested children unfortunately.

Comment: So I guess I just have to do this: .intro-cntnr {
    border-left: 1px solid darkorange;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.intro-cntnr > .intro-cntnr {
    delay..
}

.intro-cntnr > .intro-cntnr > .intro-cntnr {
    delay...
} feels a bit cheap. alrighty then.

Comment: Why not give them unique identifiers? or use scripting to cascade down them? This structure is very abnormal so it is no surprise you are running into some roadblocks support wise.

Comment: I was thinking maybe using and selecting the data-attribute which would be indexed?

Comment: That works about just as well as adding a second class

Comment: Hmm, yea maybe like a delay-transition-x?

Comment: What you name it is inconsequential

Comment: Sounds good. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Specificity** is a key solution. The longer the selector the higher the value according to what is used in selector's path.  **Specificity rules are:**

- inline styles = 1000
- ID = 100
- Class = 10
- Tag name/element = 1

you don't need to do calculations, but keep in mind that more specified means higher chance of targeting required element.  **[more on Specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)**

Following snippet shows different results based on different selectors.

```css
.intro-cntnr .intro-cntnr .intro-cntnr .intro-cntnr .intro-cntnr{
  color: red;
}

.intro-cntnr .intro-cntnr .intro-cntnr{
  color: yellow;
}

.intro-cntnr .intro-cntnr{
  color: blue;
}

.intro-cntnr{
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="intro-cntnr">
        <span class="intro-msg wht">Target value 10</span>
        <div class="intro-cntnr">
            <span class="intro-msg big wht">Target value 20</span>
            <div class="intro-cntnr">
                <span class="intro-msg gry">
                    <span class="neon">Target value 30</span>
                </span>
                <div class="intro-cntnr">
                    <div class="intro-cntnr">
                        <span class="intro-msg gry">Target value 40</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Also choosing what kind of selector to use will affect the result **[Here is a reference to css selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)**

Find what will work well with you based on the previous rules and you will get a result. or simply add IDs to elements required to style :')